# CERT.RSA or similar was not included in meta-inf folder, are there alternative locations where the certificates could be stored and viewed

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

I am trying to find out the Common Name of the Certificate Signer and the The SHA256 hash of the Code Signing Certificate for an android APK. This is a forensics analysis so I only have a copy of a released APK. What makes this question special is that META-INF does not contain any files that hold certificates. META_INF Only had various .VERSION files and a manifest.mf and an additional folder named services > with a .provider file. none of these files have any certificates. Is there another location that the certificates or at least the needed information is contained? Or Could the Certificates be named something else somewhere else?

I've tried to find any .rsa or certificate objects in meta_inf. there really seems to be none, not by a hidden file name or anything. Android studio is not having problems with a lack of certificates which leads me to believe it is kept somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

Lol the point of a challenge is to figure it out yourself! Good luck with Codebreakers

Comment: @johnathan Well sounds to me you're either some way internal or were seeking out the the answer to the same question hahaha. My initial fear was that *.RSA was left out on accident which is why I asked this question. but I was reaching out to see if anyone in this community knew of a sort of seconded location.

Comment: You’re right  I was just giving you a hard time. Have you figured it out? Do you want a hint?

Comment: sure I'd love a hint if you can point me in the right direction.

Comment: Hint: which version of code signing uses certs in the META-INF folder? And if they’re not there, what might that mean?

Comment: @johnathan Thank you for this hint. Very Much appreciated it! It was the perfect thing to kick me in the butt for thinking everything was done with java.

Comment: Was wondering if you could give the answer on where to find the certificates? I am not doing this for an assignment, but just as an android dev digging into why some of my certs are not showing up. Thanks.

Comment: Ended up using the apksigner to determine that the APK I was looking at was signed with v2.

https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/apksigner